# module tensorflow has no attribute "get_default_graph"

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have looked at all of the related questions and answers on this, and I simply cannot fix this issue!  I'm trying to go through and build a neural network for MNIST, and I get stuck on this error anytime.  Anyone else found a modern solution for this that might not have been defined in other posts?

My code:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

# Construct the model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2de137c8f569> in <module>
      3 
      4 # Construct the model
----> 5 model = models.Sequential()
      6 model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
      7 model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
     85 
     86     def __init__(self, layers=None, name=None):
---> 87         super(Sequential, self).__init__(name=name)
     88         self._build_input_shape = None
     89 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     94         else:
     95             # Subclassed network
---> 96             self._init_subclassed_network(**kwargs)
     97 
     98     def _base_init(self, name=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _init_subclassed_network(self, name)
    292 
    293     def _init_subclassed_network(self, name=None):
--> 294         self._base_init(name=name)
    295         self._is_graph_network = False
    296         self._expects_training_arg = has_arg(self.call, 'training')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _base_init(self, name)
    107         if not name:
    108             prefix = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
--> 109             name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
    110         self.name = name
    111 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     72     """
     73     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 74     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     75     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     76         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: separate Keras frontend have been used and looks like it is aimed to use TF1.x backend. Try to use tf.keras or install older TensorFlow version(see bellow) [Keras and tf.keras difference](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/)

You are using TF1.X project with TF2 framework. TF2 framework has only [compatibility version](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/get_default_graph) and it has other signature.
To use this project without changes [install TF1.X](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

> For TensorFlow 1.x, CPU and GPU packages are separate:

```
tensorflow==1.15 —Release for CPU-only
tensorflow-gpu==1.15 —Release with GPU support (Ubuntu and Windows)
```

Comment: Oh okay, I see.  Thanks!  Would you recommend I take on a different project to learn that is more modern, compatible with TF2?

Comment: Looks like I gave you wrong suggestion. I see you use separate Keras, not as part of Tensorflow. But TF2 has its own keras. Try `from tensorflow.keras import layers` and `from tensorflow.keras import models` Let me know what you get

Comment: worked like a charm.  Youre amazing . . . probably should've checked the solution worked before i accepted, but all is well! @alex K